# Calling an overloaded friend ostream insert operator with object from pointer array returns memory address

Tags: c++

I have written an overloaded insert operator which returns all data of an object. For some reason when I am trying to call it ie. cout << *pkgArray[index] it is displaying nothing, but if I do it without the * it returns a memory address. Below is the overloaded operator and my attempt to use it.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const OverNight& bObj) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << bObj.getAddress() <<  ", " << bObj.getCity() << ", " << bObj.getState() << ", "     << bObj.getZip();
  string fullAddress = ss.str();
  ss.str("");
  int newWeight = bObj.getWeight();
  ss << "$" << bObj.getUnitPrice() + bObj.getAdditional() << "/ounce";
  string costPerOunce = ss.str();
  o << left 
      << setw(1) << "|"
      << setw(20) << bObj.getsname() 
      << setw(1) << "|"
      << setw(20) << bObj.getName() 
      << setw(1) << "|"
      << setw(60) << fullAddress 
      << setw(1) << "|" 
      << setw(10) << bObj.getType()
      << setw(1) << "|"
      << setw(10) << costPerOunce
      << setw(1) << "|"
      << endl;
  o << left << "+" << setfill('-') << setw(136) << right << "+" << endl;
  o << setfill(' '); // clears the hyphen filler.
  return o;
  } 

int main() {
    Package *pkgArray[15]; // package class is abstract.
    OverNight *onObj; // assigned to pkgArray later on.
    TwoDay *tdObj; // assigned to pkgArray later on.


    // pkgArray is a pointerArray filled with objects of 2 derived classes.
    for (int index = 0; index < max; index++) {
        cout << pkgArray[index];
    }
}
```

I have tried *pkgArray[index], and &pkgArray[index], the latter returns a memory address, and the first one returns nothing. I am fairly new to c++ and feel like i've tried everything to work out this issue.

**EDIT: I have added the declaration of pkgArray and the objects which get assigned to it. I am unable to use vectors as per the assignment.**

After looking further into the problem I have discovered what is happening, is the overloaded operator is not picking up on the object being passed. I have tried dereferencing  pkgArray, and finished functionality of the overloaded insert operator in the base class, which works. Now my problem is I need to get the object of the derived class out of the dynamic array. I have tried applying precedence while dereferencing to no avail. Again the declarations are as follows.

OverNight * onObj; // pointer that will be assigned object of derived class.
TwoDay * tdObj; // pointer that will be assigned object of derived class
Package * pkgArray[15]; // this is a dynamic array of type Package which is the base class

After OverNight Objects, and TwoDay Objects are created they are assigned to the Package array.

I am trying to run a loop which calls the overridden << operator with the derived object that is stored in the dynamic array. I have learned alot throughout my struggles on this task, but apparently not enough yet to fix the issue.

Comment: What is the definition of pkgArray?

Comment: Did you overload the `operator []` for the type to which `pkgArray` belongs? It should be overloaded to return a type `OverNight&`.

Comment: We are not supposed to overload the index operator. My instructor in this class has the sloppiest code and assignments I have ever seen, which makes it really hard for me to know whether I have an error or there is something missing from the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what is going on. When I am assigning the objects of derived classes to the dynamic array of type base class, only the memory addresses are being stored as base class type. Therefore as I was running the loop I was only able to get objects of type base class (Package), and therefore the overloaded operators which are looking for objects of type OverNight, and TwoDay never get called.

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern for doing I/O with objects in a polymorphic hierarchy isn't immediately obvious. You usually implement it roughly like this though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const {
        return os << "Base\n";
    }
};

class D1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const {
        return os << "Derived 1\n";
    }
};

class D2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const {
        return os << "Derived 2\n";
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Base const &b){
    return b.write(os);
}

int main(){
    std::vector<Base *> objects;
    Base b;
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;

    objects.push_back(&b);
    objects.push_back(&d1);
    objects.push_back(&d2);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        std::cout << *objects[i];
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the result is:

```
Base
Derived 1
Derived 2
```

... just as you'd hope.

Answer (score 0):

`*pkgArray[index]` attempts to dereference an object which is not defined as a pointer, therefore * makes no sense to the compiler (it uses the first byte contained in a pointer variable and the type description to interpret the data sitting in memory, which to it are just bytes until more information through dereferencing is given).

You're probably receiving object references for which you haven't defined proper interpretation for the overloaded ostream.

Comment: pkgArray is a pointer which has object pointers assigned to it.